# Is it possible to nest command calls in the Scala Ammonite shell?

Tags: scala, ammonite

I'm trying to translate a typical UNIX command `jmap -heap $(pgrep java)` to a command for the [Ammonite-Shell](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/).

My attempt so far: `%'jmap("-heap", %'pgrep("java"))`.

I get the error `SyntaxError: found "%'jmap(\"-heap\", %'pg", expected "while" |` ... which seems to indicate the inner call to `pgrep` was not actually translated as a command call and just passed in as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ammonite, single `%` spawns a subprocess and prints out its result. In order to access command output you need to use `%%` operator, which will return `CommandResult` object. This object contains `out` field which is a stream of its output.

You can nest it this way:

```scala
%jmap("-heap", (%%pgrep("java")).out.lines.take(1))
```

Comment: Looks right, but I'm getting `%%pgrep("java")` yielding
`ammonite.ops.ShelloutException: CommandResult 1`, which seems odd; when I run it in tcsh I get exit code zero. I also get an `InteractiveShelloutException` when running just `%pgrep("java")`, which seems to confirm non-zero exit status from ammonite.

Comment: That's odd, does this subprocess output anything in Ammonite?

Comment: I tried it today and it worked  ... not sure the difference, but perhaps it was trying to attach to a java process that it didn't have access to.

Comment: Turns out, the issue was FreeBSD pgrep works differently, you need "pgrep -a" to see ancestors.